# What is the macro used to define \underline{}?

Tags: macros

How is the `\underline` command defined? And how can one make a custom underline to be used just as a horizontal line but which respects a specified height or the height of text, math input, etc and of a specific width?

Here is my first attempt:

```
\newcommand{\ndfracunderline}[1]{\ensuremath{\underline{\phantom{\dfrac{2}{3\hspace*{#1}}}}}}
```

This works just fine but the following does not:

```
\newsavebox\underlinebox

\newcommand\cunderline[3][black]{%
\newlength{\cunderlineheight}%
\settoheight{\cunderlineheight}{#3}%
{\sbox\underlinebox{\cunderlineheight\hspace*{#2}}%
  \rlap{\usebox\underlinebox}\color{#1}\rule[-1.2\dp\underlinebox]{\wd\underlinebox}{0.5pt}}}
```

Comment: LaTeX's `\underline` is defined in the kernel in the following way: `\def\underline#1{\relax
\ifmmode\@@underline{#1}\else $\@@underline{\hbox{#1}}\m@th$\relax\fi}`, where `\@@underline` has been previously `\let` to the TeX's primitive `\underline`: `\let\@@underline\underline`.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina I got that exactly when i used `\show\underline` but  thought there was another definition because of the use of `\@@underline` which seemed redundant.

Comment: @azetina: Wait, are you saying that there might be an alternative way -- other than `\tikzmark`? :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know whether this *might* be what you're after:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath
\usepackage{xcolor}% http://ctan.org/pkg/xcolor
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\newunderline}[3][black]{% \newunderline[<colour>]{<width>}{<stuff>}
  {\def\@tempa{!}%
   \def\@tempb{#2}%
   \ifx\@tempa\@tempb\relax
     \def\@tempa{\phantom}\let\maybe@hspace\@gobble%
   \else%
     \def\@tempa{\vphantom}\let\maybe@hspace\hspace%
   \fi%
   \color{#1}\underline{\@tempa{#3}\maybe@hspace{#2}}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$x$: \newunderline{1ex}{$x$} \par
$\frac{x}{y}$: \newunderline[red]{2em}{$\frac{x}{y}$} \par
$\dfrac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}$: \newunderline[blue!80!white]{!}{$\dfrac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}$}

\end{document}​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

`\newunderline[<colour>]{<width>}{<stuff>}` takes 3 arguments. The width is set to the natural width of `<stuff>` if its supplied as `!`. According to your request, it respects the *depth* of the argument, the mode (text or math) and can be of specified width (or natural).

Comment: Nice solution :-)